# Stored procedure to not to retrieve null values from table

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have table in which I have hotel names but some columns have `Null` hotel names. Now I want to get only those columns having hotel names or I don't want to get null column values from table.

My stored procedure that I wrote is

```
Alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[p_Get_HotelNamess]  
AS  
BEGIN  
   SET NOCOUNT ON;  

   SELECT
       Hotel_Info.Hotel_Name, Hotel_Info.HotelID 
   FROM 
       Hotel_Info

END
```

Comment: What are you really trying to do?  have you tried just selecting count(Hotel_Name)?  This will not count nulls.

Comment: I think you shouldn't have hotel names as null in the first place. It would be better to sort out it in the function where you inserting/updating the records. And then make `Hotel_Name` field `Not null`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try this

```
Alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[p_Get_HotelNamess]  

AS  
BEGIN  

 SET NOCOUNT ON;  

 SELECT 
     Hotel_Info.Hotel_Name, Hotel_Info.HotelID 
 FROM Hotel_Info 
 WHERE Hotel_Info.Hotel_Name IS NOT NULL

END
```